# Is there an alternative way to filter records without using Where clause

Tags: mysql

I am trying to filter the records based on a string. Is there a way I can do without using Where clause?

```
id data
1  hai
1  hello
2  how 
3  When
2  hello
```

I want to print all the id that has data 'hello' without using where clause

Comment: Would you so kind to specify the context a bit more?

Comment: You can use ''like''

Comment: Like still comes in where clause

Comment: `select * from yourtable having data='hello'`

Comment: what would be the advantage of that ?

Comment: Please add expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id,if(data='Hello',data,'') AS data FROM table;
```

or

```
SELECT id,CASE WHEN data='Hello' THEN data ELSE '' END AS data FROM table;
```

Comment: How to ignore the blank. I want only the ones with Hello. Since I am using group by because of an aggregate function. I get other results too

Comment: In that case, you could try Nick's suggestion.. this > `SELECT  id,data FROM yourtable HAVING data='hello'`